# How can I convert a column of a pandas dataframe containing string values to int/float?

Tags: python, pandas, svm

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a column that has non numeric values. How will I convert them to int/float values .

eq:

```
Col1       Col2

Lip_GD      267

Gly_hy_68   467

Hint_2      628

Jac+Jac     339

Lip_GD      234

Jac+Jac     267
```

How will I convert the column 1 to int when I read this data into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Is this the contents of one column, or a badly formatted dataframe with two columns?

Comment: What is your expected output? How would you convert 'Lip_GD' to a float?

Comment: What I was expecting is to map the unique column values into a dict eg:{"Lip_GD:"1,"Jac+Jac":2} and map this int values into the dataframe column.

Answer (score 12):

Create a mapping of each unique value in `Col1` to an index value:

```
mapping = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(df.Col1.unique())}
>>> mapping
{'Gly_hy_68': 1, 'Hint_2': 2, 'Jac+Jac': 3, 'Lip_GD': 0}
```

Then create a new column mapping the values in `Col1` back to their unique identifiers.

```
df['Col3'] = df.Col1.map(mapping)
>>> df
        Col1  Col2  Col3
0     Lip_GD   267     0
1  Gly_hy_68   467     1
2     Hint_2   628     2
3    Jac+Jac   339     3
4     Lip_GD   234     0
5    Jac+Jac   267     3
```

Comment: This worked for my case. I would like to know if there is a way to do this using scikit ?

Comment: @Krishna see my proposed answer below that uses sklearn to map categorical data to numerical values.

Answer (score 2):

**sklearn** has a built-in way to do this using [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df['Col1'])
df['Col1'] = le.transform(df['Col1'])
```

Comment: I tried this . But it gave me a type error. TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()

Comment: I guess this issue come with the kind of example data that I have given above. I tried this before posting this question over here.

Comment: This works great if there aren't multiple datatypes in the column (i.e. in the vast majority of cases).

Comment: Its been 7 years since 2015. But @zmbc, perhaps the issue was that 267 does not translate to a unique value in Col1.